# Awarding bonus reputation after bounty expires?

Tags: support, bounty

I had put a 100-point bounty on this question, as it was not getting many views or any answers.  [BabelNet API network information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367386/babelnet-api-network-information)

As the bounty period was ending, someone posted a detailed and helpful answer, but I just missed the grace period. (I had given up on getting an answer, so I wasn't paying attention.)  Since the answer didn't get 2 upvotes by the end of the grace period, I don't think it will get automatically awarded the bounty either.  Is there any way I can award the responder some bonus points myself without starting a 200-point bounty now?  (I'd happily give him points out of my current reputation points even though my first 100 were lost, but I don't really want to go up to 200).  I feel badly about not noticing the answer while the bounty was still available to be awarded.

Answer (score 4):

[You had over a day to award the bounty](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2018-03-28+16:24:07+UTC+-+2018-03-29+18:52:48+UTC), per [the post's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49367386/timeline).  Because you didn't, and because there wasn't another upvote on the answer, the bounty went unclaimed, as evidenced in the history.

> Closed, non-winning bounty for question Id = 49367386

The only way you're going to award them any bounty points now is if you start another bounty.

To understand more about this, reference [this FAQ entry on the uber-Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/175248) for more details.